# Is it wiser to have a static header, menu and footer and load center content dynamically or vice versa?

Tags: web-development, dynamic, page

When designing pages for a project that uses dynamically loaded pages/content (the website will not be accessible to search engines, so that's never a concern. Only for desktop PC use. Not for mobile phone use. Using Spring MVC), is it wiser to:
**1. Create a page with a header, menu and footer and dynamically load the content in the center, according to what the user chooses from the menu?**
OR
**2. Create separate html pages for the header, menu and footer and design a dynamic page which with center content, that will dynamically load the header, menu and footer?**

- A priority for this project is to use up as less of the network
  bandwidth as possible.
- My main concerns are that if I use iFrames to load the header, menu
  and footer, there might be problems when resizing the page.

Doesn't GMail work by loading only the center content? **Do you know how they manage to allow the User to use the back button** of the browser inspite of the content being loaded dynamically?

This is what the layout would look like:
[image]

Comment: Try AngularJS, and please don't use iframes...

Comment: Thanks, but my team can't use AngularJS for now. Moreover, my doubts will be cleared only once everything highlighted in bold are answered.

Comment: Do I answer your question?

Comment: One problem with loading via JavaScript is that Chrome and IE don't really allow it: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///F:/Projects/Frontend/header.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: You're trying to access the file `header.html` by using local access. Try using a HTTP server and then change the url scheme to `http` rather than `file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon your requirements (low network bandwidth), I think splitting your website is such a bad idea since it will result in many requests. I don't recommend dynamic loading for navigational purposes since the headers and menus are only lightweight.

Here are the answers to your questions:

1. Maybe. It depends upon the size of your dynamic content and static content.
2. There is not much difference to your first question. Separating content into parts is good idea and makes your code readable and maintainable. **I would recommend splitting it**. But, again loading dynamic content depends upon the type and size of the data.

If you want the back button kind of functionality, then go for AngularJS.

Hope this helps. :)

**UPDATE:** In that case, you can combine the static fixed assets, and then load the content dynamically using jQuery if there is no need for data persistence(like Gmail back button). Try checking out [SPDY](http://www.chromium.org/spdy) - think it will reduce network latency.

Comment: Thanks Gowtham, but are you recommending splitting the website into multiple parts or are you recommending only loading the center content?

Comment: First tell me about the type of content you need to load dynamically.

Comment: One 23x23 image, four 10x10 images, title text, a logout menu and the website's main menu, the animations of which will be controlled by jQuery. These are for the headers and menu bar. The footer will have only text. The center content can have anything from images to forms and even videos.

Comment: I've updated the question with a picture

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: By "static fixed assets" you mean the header, footer and menu?

Comment: Yes. Make them as a single part, if you're not going to touch them in future.